# GitLab CI: Two independent scheduled jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

Consider the following `gilab-ci.yml` script:

```
stages:
  - build_for_ui_automation
  - independent_job

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

build_for_ui_automation:
  dependencies: []
  stage: build_for_ui_automation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
      - fastlane/test_output
      - fastlane/report.xml
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane ui_automation
  tags:
    - ios
  only:
    - schedules
  allow_failure: false

# This should be added and trigerred independently from "build_for_ui_automation"
independent_job:
  dependencies: []
  stage: independent_job
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
      - fastlane/test_output
      - fastlane/report.xml
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane independent_job
  tags:
    - ios
  only:
    - schedules
  allow_failure: false
```

I'd like to be able to schedule these two jobs independently, but following the rules:

- **build_for_ui_automation** runs every day at **5 AM**
- **independent_job** runs every day at **5 PM**

However, with the current setup I can only trigger the whole pipeline, which will go through both jobs in sequence.

**How can I have a schedule triggering only a single job?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in gitlab inside your project go to 
`CI/CD` -> `Schedules`
press new Schedule button config the tasks as you want set the time and interval

now at the end add a variable for each one of them

now edit your gitlab.yml by adding that variable at the  `only` section

as shown here below

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#environment-variables-expressions

Answer (score 21):

**Note** - This answer used, **only-except** of GitLab CI to manipulate what job gets added to the schedule. However, as of today, GitLab has stopped active maintenance of the same commands and suggests we use **rules** instead. Here's the [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except).

I have modified the original answer to use **rules** and tested the working.

To build off @Naor Tedgi's answer, you can define a variable in your pipeline schedules. For example, set `SCHEDULE_TYPE = "build_ui"` in the schedule for build_for_ui_automation and `SCHEDULE_TYPE = "independent"` in the schedule for independent_job. Then your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file could be modified as:

```yaml
stages:
  - build_for_ui_automation
  - independent_job

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

build_for_ui_automation:
  dependencies: []
  stage: build_for_ui_automation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
      - fastlane/test_output
      - fastlane/report.xml
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane ui_automation
  tags:
    - ios
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $SCHEDULE_TYPE == "build_ui"'
      when: always
      variables:
        SCHEDULE_TYPE: "build_ui"
        ANOTHER_VARIABLE: "dummy"
      allow_failure: false

# This should be added and trigerred independently from "build_for_ui_automation"
independent_job:
  dependencies: []
  stage: independent_job
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
      - fastlane/test_output
      - fastlane/report.xml
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane independent_job
  tags:
    - ios
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $SCHEDULE_TYPE == "independent"'
      when: always
      variables:
        SCHEDULE_TYPE: "independent"
        ANOTHER_VARIABLE: "dummy123"
      allow_failure: false
```

where note the syntax change in the `only` sections to execute the jobs only during schedules and when the schedule variable is matching.

Comment: This was the solution I went with.

Comment: @RichardTopchii would you mind accepting it, since you used it? :)

Comment: Naor Tedgi was the 1st one and with a huge margin, when I actually needed that answer...

Comment: @RichardTopchii, it may help the next person who has the same problem to mark this as the answer though if that's what you use now.